# Removing AC power when laptop lid is closed doesn't suspend

Tags: laptop, power-management

While the laptop lid is closed, when I remove external power, the laptop does not suspend so i have to open the lid and close to make it suspend.

When the laptop lid is open, then I remove power, then close, it works fine.

This used to work in Ubuntu 11.04.. Didn't work after upgrading to 11.10 and still not working now that I'm on 12.04

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [bug #1014891](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1014891).

I'm affected by the bug as well; I'll attach further information to the bug report.

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying shortcoming in the current gnome-settings-manager (used to be gnome-power-manager). It does not check whether it should suspend when entering on-battery state.
Here's a work-around:

Put the following into an (executable) file /etc/pm/power.d/zzsleepiflidclosed

```
#!/bin/sh 
# If the lid is closed, then sleep when we are switched to battery mode.
case "$1" in
    true) # Going into battery mode.
      sleep 1
      grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state  &&  dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower  org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
      ;;
    false) # Going into line power mode
      ;;
    *)
        exit
        ;;
 esac
exit 0
```

I don't know why the sleep 1 pause is necessary, but without it, my lenovo won't
resume stably.